# express-session: session is not accessable in other routes

Tags: express, session, express-session

I'm using express-session to store auth token in the session. The problem i'm facing is that the session i set in the `/authenticate` (post route) is not undefined in the `/join` (get route). I have searched for the similar questions but that didn't help. Any idea what's going wrong in my code?

**server.js**

```
// All required modules loaded..

// Session config
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "mysessionsecret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 6000000 }
  })
);

// @route:authenticate
app.post("/authenticate", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid username entered" });
    }

    // Compare the password
    const compare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!compare) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Incorrect password" });
    }

    // Create token of the user ID
    jwt.sign(
      {
        userId: user.id
      },
      config.get("jwtSecret"),
      {
        expiresIn: "2d"
      },
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!req.session.user_id) {
           req.session.token = token;

           console.log(req.session.token); // Accessable here
        }
      }
    );

    res.end();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.send("Server error");
  }
});



   // @route:get /join
   app.get("/join", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.token); // token not accessable here. returns undefined

     return res.end();
   });
```

Comment: Where are your requests coming from?  Are they coming from Ajax calls?  Please show the client-side code.  It's possible the client requests are not configured properly to send cookies.  With `fetch()`, you may need to set the  `credentials: "include"` option.

Comment: I'm just using the standard <form action"/authenticate" method="post"></form>

Comment: First off, it's the `/join` route I'm asking for the client code on.  How is that sent?  Go to the Network tab in the Chrome debugger and look at the actual response coming back from the `/authenticate` form post.  See if the session cookie is in that response as a header.   Then, with the Network tab still open in the debugger, go to the `/join` route and see if the browser is sending that same cookie back to the server or not.  You need to figure out which of the two requests is not doing the cookie properly.  The Network tab will show you the details of both requests.

Comment: Both contain the same cookies. "Phpstorm-35cb17cb", "ci_session" & "remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989". there is no token cookie there

Comment: There are no response cookies

Comment: The token will not be in the cookie, that's on the server only.  The cookie is just a session ID.  The default name for the express-session cookie is `connect.sid`.  There should be a cookie with that name.  If you don't see that cookie anywhere, try `saveUninitialized:true`.  You may also try calling `req.session.save()` after you modify the session in your `/authenticate` route.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Could you kindly explain the saveUninitialize: true & req.session.save()

Comment: Well, when you set `saveUnitialized: false`, you tell express-session NOT to set your session cookie until you tell it to.  Unfortunately, the doc doesn't really say how you tell it to now set the session cookie.  My guess was that `req.session.save()` might do it or just turning `saveUnitialized` to `true` would also do it.  You can experiment with only using one of the two changes, though now you have a session cookie so you'd have to clear it in order to test with just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token will not be in the cookie, that's on the server only. The cookie is just a session ID. The default name for the express-session cookie is `connect.sid`. There should be a cookie with that name.

If you don't see that cookie anywhere, try `saveUninitialized:true`. You may also try calling `req.session.save()` after you modify the session in your `/authenticate` route.  Either one of those should cause the session cookie to get set.

When you set `saveUnitialized: false`, you tell express-session NOT to set your session cookie until you tell it to.  Unfortunately, the doc doesn't really say how you tell it to now set the session cookie.  My guess was that `req.session.save()` might do it or just turning `saveUnitialized` to `true` would also do it.  You can experiment with only using one of the two changes, though now you have a session cookie so you'd have to clear it in order to test with just one of them.